# Selenium Python browser=webdriver.Firefox() error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying out selenium's [Simple Usage](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage). Its code `driver = webdriver.Firefox()` gave an error.

This is my full code:

```
while True:
    try:
        from selenium import webdriver
        from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    except:
        print('Failed to import selenium tools, retrying...')
        continue
    else:
        print('Selenium import success!')
        break

while True:
    try:
        browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    except:
        print('Open browser error: An error occured, retrying..')
        continue
    else:
        print('Success!')
        break

browser.get('http://www.python.org')
assert "Python" in browser.title

elem = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
elem.send_keys('pycon')
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

assert "No results found" not in browser.page_source
```

and the result:

```
Selenium import success!
Open browser error: An error occured, retrying..Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\code\python project\auto.py", line 14, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 160, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. 


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\code\python project\auto.py", line 16, in <module>
    print('Open browser error: An error occured, retrying..')
```

The `Selenium import success!` result indicates that there is no problem during importing. On the other hand, `browser = webdriver.Firefox()` is the one causing problem.

How should I change it to make it work?
Note: The file I am working on it called auto.py

Comment: Have you installed geckodriver?

Comment: don't use bare excepts

Comment: Did you read the error message? Did you search this site for "'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH"? That seems like a pretty obvious error to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the Windows version of Geckodriver from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and place it somewhere convenient. Then when initializing the `browser` variable, pass the full path to `geckodriver.exe` like so:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='enter_path_here')
```

Answer (score 0):

the error message states the issue clearly: `"'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH".`

You must download geckodriver executable and make sure it is located on your PATH.

Comment: What should i do after downloading??

Comment: make sure it is on your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Place your geckodriver like this :

```
while True:
    try:
        browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = r'D:/Automation/geckodriver.exe')
    except:
        print('Open browser error: An error occured, retrying..')
        continue
    else:
        print('Success!')
        break
```

Note that `D:/Automation/geckodriver.exe` this should be geckodriver path. Just for your simplicity use I have written this.